# c# In Handler, get static variable in global

Tags: c#, scope, handler, global

My code is as bellow and I don't know why static variable didn't get its value in the global variable of the handler.

```
public class PaymentWallCancelHandler : AshxBaseHandler {

    // global variable
    private string strResultUrl = CommonModule.UserPayResultUrl;

    public override void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        base.ProcessRequest(context);
        // rest of code ...
    }
}
```

UserPayResultUrl is a static variable in other class.

```
public static class CommonModule
{ 

    public static string UserPayResultUrl
    {
        get { return BOQConfiguration.ServerConf.URLInfo.UserPayResultUrl; }
    }
}
```

When I am trying to use "strResultUrl" variable in Handler, it's value is null.

Comment: Please fix the code you have posted here. Then we can help you. Make sure to include how you want to use `strResultUrl`

Comment: Maybe `BOQConfiguration.ServerConf.URLInfo.UserPayResultUrl` is null?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply changing strResultUrl to a property?

```
public class PaymentWallCancelHandler : AshxBaseHandler {

    // global variable
    private string strResultUrl   {get{return CommonModule.UserPayResultUrl;}}
}
```